# Nil class error for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a model `Tutorial` and has_many association `Tutorialcategory` where tutorials can be connected to many tutorial categories. Tutorials model and controller are working fine but categories are not. I am able to add categories but can not edit them, I am getting 'undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class' error while accessing edit page for tutorialcategory.

I have defined route as follows

```
resources :tutorialcategories do
    end
```

following is my model definition

```
class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tutorialcategories
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add categories but not edit them then you must load a `@tutorial_category` variable in your edit action, something like this:

```
def edit
  @tutorial_category = TutorialCategory.find params[:id]
end
```